# Deploying React + Express app to Heroku resulting in "Nothing was returned from render"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, heroku

Everything works locally for me -- no errors when running the app. I saw other posts about this issue, where there were problems with how a component was returning JSX or returning JSX on a condition. However, I looked through all of my code (I have a pretty big project right now, so there's no way I could post the code for it all), and encountered none of the problems with my return statements. I don't even know where the problem could be originating from, as everything works locally and the error doesn't tell me where in my code the error is. Does anyone have any tips for how to debug this issue?

The full error is "Component(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null."

Comment: Please give a [mre].

Comment: I'm not sure how to give a minimal reproducible example for this, since I'm not sure where in m project is causing the issue. I just know that I never got this error when testing my project locally with npm start, but once I deployed my project with heroku, when I went to my deployed app, I get a blank page with the given error i nthe console

Answer (score 0):

In case you haven't figured out the problem yet.

---

1. Your `return` statement and its opening parenthesis should be on the same line. This should be indicated by your compiler, since you say your code runs locally then my guess this is not your error.

do:

```js
function foo() {
    return (
        this.someValue
    )
}
```

or

```
function foo() {
    return this.someValue
}
```

do not:

```js
function foo() {
    return
    (
        this.someValue
    )
}
```

---

2. Another problem I've come across with heroku and react is that heroku doesn't like comments right after a return statement.

do:

```js
function foo() {
    return (
        this.someValue
        // this is fine
    )
}
```

do not:

```
function foo() {
    return (
        // delete this line
        this.someValue
    )
}
```

---

Have a banana :)

```
 _
//\
V  \
 \  \_
  \,'.`-.
   |\ `. `.       
   ( \  `. `-.                        _,.-:\
    \ \   `.  `-._             __..--' ,-';/
     \ `.   `-.   `-..___..---'   _.--' ,'/
      `. `.    `-._        __..--'    ,' /
        `. `-_     ``--..''       _.-' ,'
          `-_ `-.___        __,--'   ,'
             `-.__  `----"""    __.-'
                  `--..____..--'
```